# node-pre-gyp install error on npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-gyp, grpc-node

I was trying to follow the react in action book. - [book's project repo](https://github.com/react-in-action/letters-social/tree/master)

But on doing `npm install` on Ubuntu, I am getting

```
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.7.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.7.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.`
```

I have also tried to update my node and npm version and then npm install but it's still not working .
Help me to fix this irritating error .

**Edit:**

I have tried to fix this using almost 10 answers from SO as well as github but none of them works and also some of the answer is for windows or mac and not for ubuntu. I have tried the answers to [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnpm%5D+npm+ERR%21%2C+node-pre-gyp) too.

Comment: I remember having this problem as well. I can't remember how I fixed it. I would love to see what the response is to this. In the end I may have just sudo force installed grpc because I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: do you have a some proxy? In my same case I turn off ssl-checks for npm install: `npx cross-env NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 npm i`

Answer (score 1):

This issue just wasted my day. I went through a lot of solutions like installing node-pre-gyp, uninstall and reinstall node and npm, cleared the cache and node modules and reinstall installed the dependency. But none of the solutions worked.

At last, I fixed it by downgrading the npm version from `v10.xx` to `v9.9.0`. Steps that I followed (for mac):

1. Open terminal and type `sudo npm install -g n`
2. Once step 1 done, type `n 9.9.0` to downgrade the npm version

Hope it helps :)